# To extend or not to extend vocabulary for instruction tuning

Tags: nlp, llm

I want to fine tune a base llm using an instruction dataset. In order to minimize VRAM footprint I want to use SFTTrainer and QLora. My prompt can take the following structure:

```
    [INST] <<SYS>>\nSystem_Message_Here\n<</SYS>>\n\nUser_Msg_1 [/INST]_Msg_1 [INST] User_Msg_2 [/INST] Asst_Msg_2 [INST] User_Msg_3 [/INST]
```

I am wondering if I shall add to my tokenizer new tokens *[INST]* *<< SYS>>* *<</ SYS>>* or *[/INST]* - or if I shall keep the base model vocabulary ?